# R POSIXct date equality not working as expected

Tags: r

When I compare seemingly the same dates in R using the POSIXct library, R still returns FALSE when it looks like it should return TRUE. Is there anything that looks off? Here is my code and the output. When I write the dates to a text file and read them back and convert them to POSIXct dates, R returns FALSE and that they are not the same dates.

```
#dataframe from previous source
data
write.table(data,"latest.txt",sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)

prev = read.delim("latest.txt",sep=",")
prev$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(prev$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Etc/GMT-8"))

prev$date
data$date

class(prev$date)
class(data$date)

prev$date == data$date
```

Output from this snippet

```
                 date  V1 
1 2021-09-16 22:05:32 100
[1] "2021-09-16 22:05:32 +08"
[1] "2021-09-16 22:05:32 +08"
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
[1] FALSE
```

Here is some input data that I have the problem with

```
structure(list(date = structure(1631804267.5, tzone = "Etc/GMT-8", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), CO_RAMP = 258.183833333333, NO_RAMP = 9.85633333333333, 
    NO2_RAMP = 16.3028333333333, O3_RAMP = 15.3968333333333, 
    CO2_RAMP = 242.283333333333, T_RAMP = 13.6633333333333, RH_RAMP = 65.675, 
    PM1_RAMP = 2.20083333333333, PM_RAMP = 2.90366666666667, 
    PM10_RAMP = 2.98666666666667), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: You should provide some input data.

Comment: Added some input data in my post.

Comment: to create usable input data pleaswe use `dput()`  or similar since your showcase isn't easily converted into formats workable in r

Comment: Used dput() and changed my input data to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can be reproduced with -

```
data <- data.frame(date = Sys.time())
write.table(data,"latest.txt",sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
prev = read.delim("latest.txt",sep=",")
prev$date <- as.POSIXct(prev$date)

prev$date
#[1] "2021-09-17 14:08:48 +08"
data$date
#[1] "2021-09-17 14:08:48 +08"
class(prev$date)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
class(data$date)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
prev$date == data$date
#[1] FALSE
```

If you drop the attributes and compare both the time as character it works.

```
as.character(prev$date) == as.character(data$date)
#[1] TRUE
```

However, this I think is a timezone issue. If you keep the timezone as UTC it works as expected.

```
data <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(as.character(Sys.time()), tz = 'UTC'))
write.table(data,"latest.txt",sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
prev = read.delim("latest.txt",sep=",")
prev$date <- as.POSIXct(prev$date, tz = 'UTC')
prev$date == data$date
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Switching the timezone to UTC for me returns FALSE for my data, but returns TRUE for your example, the mystery only deepens. I'm going to use your as.character comparison as it works for my needs. Thank you for your help!